# Why does OllyDbg label data segment as read only?

Tags: windows, x86, ollydbg

I'm working on this problem: [Challenge 53](https://challenges.re/53/)

When compiling with `cl c53.c /Fac53.asm /MD` in VS2019 X86 Development Console and loading the `.exe` into OllyDbg, I found OllyDbg labels all segments of `c53` as `R`:

[image]

Maybe there is some misunderstanding here, but why is the data segment not writable? Actually when I step into the program I can see the beginning of memory part of "Hello, world!" been overwritten by "Goodbye!" and there was no segfault (unlike in Linux there IS segfault and <s>I'm still trying to figure out why, but that's a different question</s> when checking `c53.o` in IDA it tells me the string "Hello World!" is in **rodata** so that segfault makes perfect sense):

[image]

To verify that the strings are indeed in data segment, not in rodata segment, I checked the assembly code:

```
_DATA   SEGMENT
$SG10125 DB 'Goodbye!', 00H
    ORG $+3
$SG10126 DB 'Result: %s', 0aH, 00H
$SG10129 DB 'Hello, world!', 0aH, 00H
_DATA   ENDS
```

Comment: Could you share the .exe file? Just upload it to VirusTotal and post the SHA256 of it here.

Comment: @Utkonos sorry for being late. I somehow removed part of the VM so now it is a bit difficult to find it back. I'll try again once I build a new VM and redo Challenge 53.